# C Access Violation error

Tags: c, pointers

When I try to execute the following code in Visual Studio I get a data access error. I looked it up but saw that it happens when I try to modify a string literal which is a read only.

```
char *my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *source)
{
    int i;
    while(*dest)
    {
        *dest++ = *source++;
    }
    return dest;
}

 int main()
 {
    char str[80] = "Hello, there!";
    char *strPtr = NULL;

    my_strcpy (strPtr, str);    

    return 0;
}

error:
Unhandled exception at 0x01163C91 in PtrStrArr.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

I am unable to identify where I am modifying a string literal. I even declared the array as a constant. If I remove the declaration

```
  char *strPtr = NULL;
```

I get an error

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'strPtr' is being used without being initialized.
```

Could you please point me to my mistake here?

EDIT:

Thanks to all the answers I was able to correct my code and get the ouput as below.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<malloc.h>

 char *my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *source)
 {
    char *retVal = dest;
    int i=0;
    while(*source != '\0')
    {
        *dest++ = *source++;
    }
    *dest++ = '\0';
    return retVal;
  }

  void print_array(char *str)
  {
    int i;
    while(*str)
    {
        printf("%c",*str++);
    }
  }

  int main()
  {
    char str[80] = "What up dude?";
    char* strPtr;
    strPtr = (char *)(malloc(sizeof str));
    print_array (str);
    printf("\n");
    my_strcpy (strPtr, str);    
    print_array (strPtr);
    return 0;
  }
```

I do have one question though. In all your answers you have not made the cast from void* to char* when using malloc. But when I tried it out I had to explicitly

```
strPtr = (char *)(malloc(sizeof str));
```

I am using malloc in the right way?
Thanks to every one for your answers.

Comment: Aside from what Jim mentioned, You copy *into* the destination until the *source* is null, not the other way around.

Comment: In regard to the need for the cast, it sounds like you've told VS that this is C++ source. You need to tell it that it's C source. Beware though that VS only implements C89, not C99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it happens when I try to modify a string literal which is a read only

That's just one of the many ways it can happen. Another is trying to store into `NULL`, which is what you're doing here:

```
char str[80] = "Hello, there!";
char *strPtr = NULL;

my_strcpy (strPtr, str);
```

You want to copy `str` to somewhere, but where? You haven't provided any memory to store into.
Consider

```
char str[80] = "Hello, there!";
char str2[sizeof str];

my_strcpy (str2, str);
```

or

```
char str[80] = "Hello, there!";
char* strptr = malloc(sizeof str);
if (!strptr)
    /* do something on out-of-memory */;

my_strcpy (strptr, str);
```

Also, `my_strcpy` is looping until it finds the `NUL` in the *destination*, which is of course wrong ... you can't look at the destination until you've stored something there. And, you aren't storing the NUL into the destination. Consider the simple loop

```
while ((*dest++ = *source++) != '\0')
    ;
```

Finally, you probably don't want to return `dest`, which now points past the `NUL`. Either declare `my_strcpy` to `return` `void` and don't return anything, or if you want it to have the same semantics as `strcpy`, save the original value of `dest` and `return` that, e.g.,

```
char* retval = dest;

while ((*dest++ = *source++) != '\0')
    ;

return retval;
```

or

```
for (char* destp = dest; (*destp++ = *source++) != '\0';)
    ;

return dest;
```

Pick the style you prefer.

Comment: Next problem; he is looping through `dest` until *it* is null and then returning the value.

Comment: Ahhh, but I leap in and correct at a near instantaneous rate :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Also when I did try to do this                                              char str[80] = "What up dude?";
char *strPtr = malloc(sizeof str);                                         I get an error saying value of type void cannot be used to initialize type char*.

Comment: Also thanks for the insight when using return dest. I am new to pointers, here from C# so trying to learn as much as I can. Thanks again

Comment: @fritzrage "I get an error saying value of type void cannot be used to initialize type char" -- you would get that if you compile with a C++ compiler rather than a C compiler. They are different languages.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Check your arithmetic, silly. Given the choice between me lying and you being inept and incompetent, always pick the latter. And even if I were 74, why wouldn't you think so? There are plenty of 74 year old programmers around, and some of them are  SO members. Finally: why are you trolling here? This answer isn't about me or my age.

Answer (score 5):

**First:**

You don't allocate memory for `dest` array:

```
char *strPtr = NULL;    <-- allocate memory here
// strPtr = malloc(lenght + 1); // +1 for \0 chaar
my_strcpy (strPtr, str);
```

**Second:**

Also, in string copy function loop should run while `*source` is nul.

```
while(*source){
```

**Third:**

You don't add `\0` at the end to `dest` after loop-ends, add `*dest = '\0';` after while loop in string copy code.

**Fourth:**

You returns `dest` while in loop you increments it!

Try this code:

```
char * my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *source)
{
    dest = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);  //allocate memory 
    tdest = dest;  // store it to return 
    while(*source) // copy until source terminate at \0
    {
        *tdest++ = *source++;
    }
    *tdest = '\0'; // add nul termination in dest string 
    return dest; // return allocated memory address 
}
```

Note that memory allocation is done inside string copy function.

By the way, I didn't change your function prototype and function name but what are you trying to build is called [**`strdup()`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/functions/strdup.html). Because memory allocation is done inside function and duplicate string is returned so you don't need to pass first argument.

So as @[Jim Balter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544557/jim-balter) also reviewed my answer semantically correct way to write function is:

```
char * my_strdup(const char *source)
{
    dest = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);  //allocate memory 
    tdest = dest;  // store it to return 
    while(*source) // copy until source terminate at \0
    {
        *tdest++ = *source++;
    }
    *tdest = '\0'; // add nul termination in dest string 
    return dest; // return allocated memory address 
}
```

call it as:

```
char* strPtr = my_strdup(str);
```

It you want memory allocation in main function and keep string copy function simple then please read Jim Balter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20877884/1673391).

Comment: You're ignoring the value of the dest argument. The malloc should be in the caller, or the function shouldn't take a dest argument, though that significantly changes its semantics.

Comment: @JimBalter yes that is what I think I added at lats in my answer. Because OP was returning address so I did memory allocation inside function.

Comment: But my point is that you still passing in a value for dest, but then ignoring it, and you're ignoring the return value, so you're both failing to copy into the caller's destination (strptr) and you're leaking memory. OP *does* want `strcpy` and *doesn't* want `strdup`.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes Jim I understand your point I tried to improve after your suggestion. Hope it will help OP else I refer your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you fixed the bugs (although I still don't think the OP wants strdup), but there's no need to initialize strPtr to NULL. Don't initialize it at all, or do `char* strPtr = my_strdup(str)`. Anyway, I appreciate your consideration of my input.

Comment: @JimBalter Hmm..fair enough I do it.

Comment: " Because OP was returning address so I did memory allocation inside function" -- note that standard `strcpy` also returns the dest address but doesn't do allocation.

Comment: P.S. Please fix spelling of "Forth" -> "Fourth". :-)

Comment: @JimBalter Yes I check [`strcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/functions/strcpy.html) you are correct. I do correct my spells also. Thanks you very much!

Comment: I hope the OP returns and appreciates all our efforts. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you Jim and Girjesh. You've given me two ways to work this out :) Your help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to allocate memory for `strPtr` before calling your copy function

```
strPtr=malloc(sizeof(str));
```